# Encrypting mssql queries

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, encryption

I have a weird question,

Is it possible to encrypt mssql sp or triggers or even queries? like in php base64 system.

If it's possible, can someone provide me a link of the method or a small tutorial explaining how to use the encrypted method to be read from sql?!

all I want is a small encryption method that allows me to encrypt my queries and let the sql read it over the encryption itself. just like php

Comment: Note that BASE64 isn't an encryption, it's a simple encoding

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want encryption to happen in SQL itself. I would suggest against this as it kind of defeats the whole purpose of encrypting the data. The reason behind it is usually that if a 3rd party gains access to your database (and not application code), they still cannot read the data. If you set encryption to happen in SQL, then they will be able to decrypt the data.

If this is not what you've wanted, then sorry for my wasted reply.